# MarkLogic integration with pySpark

Tags: pyspark, marklogic

Hi I have requirement of connecting **MarkLogic with pySpark**. Is there any reference you can guide me through where I can start with. I found few blogs where they have suggested using "**MarkLogic Connector for Hadoop**", but since it will **deprecated starting with MarkLogic release 10.0-3** so I am looking for other alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MarkLogic Extended REST API` (using `JavaScript` or `XQuery`) - [Extending the REST API](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions).

Also you have the option to evaluate an Ad-Hoc `JavaScript/Xquery` Query - [Evaluating an Ad-Hoc Query](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions#id_67576).

Hope that helps.

Comment: The out of the box REST api might suffice as well. I'd avoid sending eval code across, and rather use Data Services or REST extensions as suggested above. You can find more on Data Services here: https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/wiki/Data-Services. Note, that these services are not exclusive to Java or Java Client API..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using MarkLogic rest API. Thanks for help @Ashish.
I even wrote an story on medium how we can achieve this.
https://medium.com/@anshumankaku/ingesting-data-from-cdp-hive-into-marklogic-43e4768be271